# How to add field to mongoose query result?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

```
exports.getCityCascade = function (req, res) {
var result = {};
Province.find().exec(function (err, provinces) {
    result.provinces = provinces;
    var provinceCount = 0;
    async.whilst(
        function () {
            return provinceCount < provinces.length
        }
        , function (callback) {
            City.find({province: provinces[provinceCount].id}).exec(function (err, cities) {
                if (err) {
                    callback(err);
                } else {
                    result.provinces[provinceCount].cities =cities;  
                }
                provinceCount++;
                callback(null , result);
            });
        }, function (err, result) {
            if (err) return res.jsonp({message: err.message});
            return res.jsonp({
                status: '200',
                results: result});
        }
    )
})
}
```

When I add the `cities` field to provinces, It seems doesn't work. the response body doesn't contain the filed `cities`.  How to fix it?  Any advice would be very helpful.

Comment: Where are you incrementing `provinceCount `? I mean, looks like an infinite loop.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me.I fixed it just now.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is just a conflict between variable names: you declared a `var result` outside `Province.find()`, but the `async.whilst()` also uses `result` as the second argument of its callback function. Just rename one of them and it should work.